# How to seperate declaration and implementation of a templated class with a default template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I like to separate the declaration and implementation of my classes. I know that the implementation of class templates and function also has to go into the header file, that's not the problem.

I'm having trouble implementing this class:

```
template <size_t S, std::enable_if_t<(S > 0), int> = 0>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
}
```

So far I have tried:

```
template<size_t S>
Foo<S>::Foo() {}
```

which failed with

> error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
>
> error C2976: 'Foo<S,<__formal>>' : too few template arguments

and

```
template<size_t S, int i>
Foo<S, i>::Foo() {}
```

which failed with

> error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
>
> error C3855: 'Foo<S,<unnamed-symbol>>' : template parameter '__formal' is incompatible with the declaration

I have also tried changing the template declaration to

`template <size_t S, typename = std::enable_if_t<(S > 0)>>`

which also failed with the first error message.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize template functions (that's what you're doing in the first snippet). If you're asking about how to define it outside the class, try this:

```
template <size_t S, std::enable_if_t<(S > 0), int> j>
Foo<S, j>::Foo(){}
```

You cannot just replace `std::enable_if_t<(S > 0), int>` by `int`, as the definitions are not equivalent (the `enable_if` one SFINAEs out the `S == 0` case).

[<kbd>Live snippet</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/840d4364f29c5757)

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
template <size_t S>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
};

template <size_t S>
Foo<S>::Foo() { }

template <>
class Foo<0>;
```

In this particular case, I'm not sure adding SFINAE gives you any extra benefits. It's possible that even the explicit specialization is unnecessary, and just a simple `static_assert(S > 0, "!")` would suffice.

Comment: The condition is actually a bit more complicated. I just dumbed it down for the example. Listing all invalid values would be impractical. Good point about `static_assert` though. I guess I just got too excited about trying out `enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way of doing this?

I suppose the second one you've tried, with the `typename`.

Given

```
template <size_t S, typename = std::enable_if_t<(S > 0)>>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
};
```

the constructor can be defined as

```
template <std::size_t S, typename T>
Foo<S, T>::Foo() {}
```

A full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <size_t S, typename = std::enable_if_t<(S > 0)>>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
};

template <std::size_t S, typename T>
Foo<S, T>::Foo() {}

int main ()
 {
   Foo<12U>  f12;   // compile
   // Foo<0U>   f0; // compilation error
 }
```